# How do I do this simple 301 redirect from index.htm to root?

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I've read various reference sites on redirection, and to be honest I understand very little.

I currently have standard WordPress mod_rewrite redirect rules in my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Quite a few of my referrers go to a old URL `http://www.example.com/index.htm`, which gives them an error, and I want them to be seamlessly redirected to `http://www.example.com/`. I believe a 301 redirect is the best method for this.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will translate all occurrences of index.html or index.htm to just the directory, recursively.

Comment: When you say "recursively", you mean this will work for all subdirectories within the site, I assume?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For all subdirectories.

Comment: That works great, many thanks. Just to note that I realised I needed to put this rule before my existing Wordpress one.

Comment: That did work for me as well. I had to remove the / from /$1 to make it work for my config (Apache 2.4.7).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but i guess that should be `RewriteRule ^index.htm$ / [R=301]` or something like this

Answer (score -2):

Create an index.html, containing the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=the-other-url">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
You will be redirected...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Where "seconds" is the duration of the delay (in seconds) before the redirection. Set a "0" for instant redirect.

"the-other-url" is http://www.example.com/index.php

Comment: This is not a 301 redirect, depends on the client, and is generally considered bad practice.